# Making a Tic Tac Toe using ASCII

Tags: c++, ascii

```
char choice, a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd', e = 'e', f = 'f', g = 'g', h = 'h', i = 'i';

if (a+b+c == 264 || d+e+f == 264 || g+h+i == 264 || a+d+g == 264 || b+e+h == 264 || c+f+i == 264 || a+e+i == 264 || c+e+g == 264) {
            finish = true;
            cout << "p1 win" << endl;
}
else if (a+b+c == 237 || d+e+f == 237 || g+h+i == 237 || a+d+g == 237 || b+e+h == 237 || c+f+i == 237 || a+e+i == 237 || c+e+g == 237) {
            finish = true;
            cout << "p2 win" << endl;
}
```

Im using ASCII calculation to determine if player 1 or 2 win in a game of tic tac toe.

Do you think the sum can overlap with other possibilities?

Comment: Suppose I answered "no", what would it help you?

Comment: Consider using -1=O, 1=X, and 0 = space.   then your sums will be -3 or +3 for the win.   -2 and +2 will be for combinations that a win is possible.  That will avoid any overlap.